# Laravel & Angular : Form with File

Tags: forms, file, angularjs, input, laravel

I develop a website with Laravel and AngularJs for my studies,
But i've a problem with "file" on form. I haven't access to my file into my controller.

This my forms :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Nom :</label>
        <input type="text" id="name"  ng-model="file.name" required>
        <label class="control-label" for="file">Veuillez choisir un fichier :</label>
        <input type="file" id="file"  ng-model="file.file" required>

        <button type="submit" ng-click="addFile()">Ajouter le fichier</button>
</form>
```

This is my controller :

```
public function addDocument($id) {

    return Response::json(array('name' => Input::get('name'),'file'=> Input::get('file')));

}
```

And it's my Angular Controller :

ProjectController.controller('Documents', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

```
$scope.projectId = $routeParams.projectId;

$scope.addFile= function() {

     $http.post('project/addDocument/' + $routeParams.projectId, $scope.file).success(function(data) {
        $scope.flash=data.flash;
      });
};
```

});

I've for result : file: "C:\fakepath\nodejs-1280x1024.png"
name: "salut"

It seems ok,  but when i wanna access to my file with Input::file() and use function like Input::file('file)->getSize() (i've error : try to access to non-object file ).
i have Input::file(file) == null. Someone can help me to resolve it ?

Thank's !
Have a good night :)

I've rebuild all my app with node.js and have same problem, i've solved it by my angularjs controller :

var fileUpload;

```
 $scope.onFileSelec = function($files) {
    fileUpload = $files;
    $scope.flash = 'coucou';
 }

//send file to api
$scope.onFileSelect = function() {
//$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.length; i++) {
  var $file = fileUpload[i];
  $upload.upload({
    url: '/cleanz/api/documents/add/' + $routeParams.projectId + '?descr=' + $scope.file.description,
    file: $file,
    progress: function(e){}
  }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // file is uploaded successfully
    console.log(data);
  }); 
}
```

}

Comment: Did you work this out?

Comment: Yes i've solved it. I've edit my main post, you can check it ! :)

Comment: Can you confirm it this code is ok for laravel ? i've only test with express and node.js.

Comment: Trying to add file upload with angular to laravel.  Will post back with results, based on this post (fingers crossed it just works :)